# Universal links deep linking not working for certain links

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Our app has enabled deeplinking using universal links

This is what the AASA file on the server looks like

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "team.com.company.product",
            "paths": ["/dashboards/*", "/lakes/*", "/dashboards-next/*", "/embed/lakes/*"]
        }]
    }
}
```

This is the manifest file

```
<string>applinks:*.company.com/dashboards</string>
<string>applinks:*.company.com/lakes</string>
<string>applinks:*.company.com/dashboards-next</string>
<string>applinks:*.company.com/embed/lakes</string>
```

The `"/dashboards/*", "/lakes/*", "/dashboards-next/*"` seem to working fine with the app but
`"/embed/lakes/*"` urls don't seem to working

Eg:
https://base.dev.company.com/lakes/jCzwyW924vnnh4k5Yx7B8t9H99j4Rhd9 works fine
https://base.dev.company.com/embed/lakes/jCzwyW924vdnhFk5Yx7B8t9H99j4Rhd9 doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

The issue turned out to be that the manifest file was updated and hosted on the subdomain but it wasn't updated on the main domain.